# Why does "import {} from ../entities" work and not "import {} from src/entities" in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

This is probably a really basic question, but I'm following a React tutorial, and my file structure is as follows:

[image: file structure]

In my `user.ts` file, I am trying to import both the User entity and a Context from `types.ts`, and Intellisense autocompletes the import statements into

```
import { User } from 'src/entities/User';
import { MyContext } from 'src/types';
```

However when I run the program using `yarn nodemon dist/index.js`, the error I get is:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'src/entities/User'
Require stack:
- /Users/jaidynbelbin/Desktop/React Projects/LIReddit-Server/dist/resolvers/user.js
- /Users/jaidynbelbin/Desktop/React Projects/LIReddit-Server/dist/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaidynbelbin/Desktop/React Projects/LIReddit-Server/dist/resolvers/user.js:28:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/jaidynbelbin/Desktop/React Projects/LIReddit-Server/dist/resolvers/user.js',
    '/Users/jaidynbelbin/Desktop/React Projects/LIReddit-Server/dist/index.js'
  ]
}
```

The issue is fixed by changing the import statements to:

```
import { User } from '../entities/User';
import { MyContext } from '../types';
```

My question is why? Is it something to do with the `"watch": "tsc -w",` command in my `package.json` file?

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

compiler try to find the module in relative path, so:

in your tsconfig. tsconfig setting use the baseUrl setting, this can solve the problem:

```
"CompilerOptions": {
    “baseUrl”: “./src”,
}
```

> Setting baseUrl informs the compiler where to find modules. All module imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the baseUrl

here is documentation from typescript:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be working. Changing to it from "." to "src" and the import statements to ... from 'entities/User' shows no errors, and hovering over the module path shows the correct file path, but the error remains. It still only will accept ../entities/User.

Comment: how about “./src”?

Comment: Still nope. I've tried just about every combination I can think of and none are working! I can just use ../ in the future, but it'd be nice for me not have to manually change it every time Intellisense imports something.

Comment: @JaidynBelbin maybe another better option, use a plugin "relative path", this is more comfortable in practice, actually I use this one in my vs code. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath :-)

Comment: Oh, that's a nice extension, thanks! Happy to just work around this issue for now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { User } from 'src/entities/User';
import { MyContext } from 'src/types';
```

those will lines in `user.ts` will try to to import the modules relative to the directory which `user.ts` reside in which is `resolver`. that is like as you have typed:

```
import { User } from './src/entities/User';
import { MyContext } from './src/types';
```

here `.` mean the current working directory which is `resolver` so the path become:

`resolver/src/entities/User` which you don't have.

the same is true for `MyContext` the path become `resolver/src/entities/MyContext`.

but by using the relative path typescript is able to resolve the path for those modules correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you have multiple questions here and I will try to respond to all one by one :).

- you are trying to run the application from the build files i.e. `yarn nodemon dist/index.js` generally dist folder is used to keep build files and src is where actual development happens.
- Your issue is fixed as you have changed your path from absolute path to relative path. The reason it was not working earlier with the absolute path is due to your **webpack configuration**, if you want to use the absolute path you need to update webpack.json file.
- There are two ways to do it, one way is directly resolving the source to src folder.

```js
var path = require('path');

// ...
resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve('./src'),
  ],
}
```

Now you can import directly as `import { User } from 'entities/User'`

- Another way is to set up an alias. you can set up an alias for subfolders as well which will be helpful in case of monorepo or a huge repo or even in small one to think of :)

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    entities: path.resolve('./src/entities')
  }
},
```

Now you can import from entities like this `import { User } from 'entities/User'`.

Since you are using typescript compiler `tsc -w` you can update your `tsconfig.json` file to achieve the same thing.

```js
compilerOptions: {
  // ...

  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "entities/*": [
      "entities/*"
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: So would I have to do that for every subfolder I create in the future?

Comment: Not needed in your case, defining baseUrl should be just fine.